# How to partition the following s3 directory?

Tags: amazon-s3, partitioning, amazon-athena

Suppose I have an  S3 directory which looks like -

```
Root Folder - Electronics
Folders inside Electronics - Samsung, Sony, LG 
Folders inside each of Samsung, Sony, Toshiba -  Television, Microwave, Fridge
```

So basically I want to create a table in Athena which partitions firstly based on Brand Name, and then on Product Name

How to create such a partition?

My table already has columns **Serial Number, Brand, Product Type, Manufacturing Date, Price**.
How to do effective partitioning?
I want to do it using ALTER table

Comment: A common way to describe partitions in using `brand=Samsung` format. If you rename your folders (move objects) to this format and then create a table that will take the folder structure automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, that would be like this :

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD
PARTITION (brand = 'Samsung', ProductType = 'Television') LOCATION 's3://mystorage/Electronics/Samsung/Television/'
PARTITION (brand = 'Sony', ProductType = 'Television') LOCATION 's3://mystorage/Electronics/Sony/Television/'
PARTITION (brand = 'Sony', ProductType = 'Microwave') LOCATION 's3://mystorage/Electronics/Sony/Microwave/'
...
```

Comment: So this means, there's no easier way other than this?

Comment: @DawsonSmith I'm afraid not. unless you prepare your query it using dynamic sql and then run it

Comment: Getiing an error - SemanticException table is not partitioned but partitioned spec exits

Comment: is it an external table? It shild be an external table if you want to partition it